# How to get the total amount and difference of all 'input type = "number"' stepper.js on the page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I use stepper.js (https://github.com/gijsroge/stepper.js) to customize the `'input type = "number"'` in the price calculator and encountered a problem when writing javascript code.

There are several `'input type = "number"'` with the date attribute `'data-value'` and the total value of the stepper is made up of the product `'input type = "number"'` and `'data-value'`.

It is necessary when increasing the value (clicking on "+") of one of the steppers, add it to the total amount of 3 steppers, and decreasing (pressing on "-"), on the contrary, reduce the total amount.

My code separately displays the value of each stepper, but I did not succeed in correctly displaying the total value when adding and subtracting.

I am new to javascript. Can you help me write the code correctly so that it is calculated correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Step</title>
<style media="screen">
 *,
 *:before,
 *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .stepper {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
 }

 .stepper__input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
 }

 .stepper__input:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
 }

 .stepper__input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
 .stepper__input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
 }

 .stepper__controls [spinner-button="up"],
 .stepper__controls [spinner-button="down"] {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: all ease 0.25s;
 }

 .stepper__controls [spinner-button="up"]:hover,
 .stepper__controls [spinner-button="down"]:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  border-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .stepper--style-2 {
  max-width: 140px;
 }

 .stepper--style-2 .stepper__input {
  padding-left: 3.25rem;
  padding-right: 3.25rem;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="up"],
 .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="down"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 2.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="up"] {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
 }

 .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="down"] {
  left: 0;
  margin-right: -1px;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<section>

<p>Stepper 1</p>
<div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="10">
  <div class="stepper__controls">
    <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
    <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Stepper 2</p>
<div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="20">
  <div class="stepper__controls">
    <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
    <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Stepper 3</p>
<div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="30">
  <div class="stepper__controls">
    <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
    <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
  </div>
</div>

</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/stepper.js@1.0.3/dest/stepper.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
 var stepp = document.getElementsByClassName('stepper__input');

 for (var i = 0; i < stepp.length; i++) {
  stepp[i].onchange = function steppChange(evt) {
    var total = parseInt(evt.target.getAttribute('data-value') * evt.target.value);
    console.log(total);
  }
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse `stepper__input` one again

```
for (var i = 0; i < stepp.length; i++) {
  stepp[i].onchange = function steppChange(evt) {
    var total = 0
    for (var j = 0; j < stepp.length; j++) {
      total += parseInt(stepp[j].getAttribute('data-value') * stepp[j].value);
    }
    console.clear();
    console.log(total);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 2!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Step</title>
  <style media="screen">
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      padding: 1em;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .stepper {
      display: inline-block;
      max-width: 120px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .stepper__input {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      padding: .375rem .75rem;
      border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }
    
    .stepper__input:focus {
      color: #333;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-color: #c4c4c4;
      outline: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
    }
    
    .stepper__input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    .stepper__input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .stepper__controls [spinner-button="up"],
    .stepper__controls [spinner-button="down"] {
      display: flex;
      align-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 0;
      outline: none;
      border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 50%;
      font-size: 1.375em;
      line-height: 0;
      transition: all ease 0.25s;
    }
    
    .stepper__controls [spinner-button="up"]:hover,
    .stepper__controls [spinner-button="down"]:hover {
      background-color: #333;
      border-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .stepper--style-2 {
      max-width: 140px;
    }
    
    .stepper--style-2 .stepper__input {
      padding-left: 3.25rem;
      padding-right: 3.25rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="up"],
    .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="down"] {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: -1px;
      width: 2.5rem;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="up"] {
      right: 0;
      margin-left: -1px;
    }
    
    .stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="down"] {
      left: 0;
      margin-right: -1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>

    <p>Stepper 1</p>
    <div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="10">
      <div class="stepper__controls">
        <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
        <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Stepper 2</p>
    <div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="20">
      <div class="stepper__controls">
        <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
        <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Stepper 3</p>
    <div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="30">
      <div class="stepper__controls">
        <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
        <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/stepper.js@1.0.3/dest/stepper.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var stepp = document.getElementsByClassName('stepper__input');

    for (var i = 0; i < stepp.length; i++) {
      stepp[i].onchange = function steppChange(evt) {
        var total = 0
        for (var j = 0; j < stepp.length; j++) {
          total += parseInt(stepp[j].getAttribute('data-value') * stepp[j].value);
        }
        console.clear();
        console.log(total);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can get all inputs and each time there is a change in the input, you can compute the total regardless of increment or decrement, consider the following jQuery solution:

```js
$(".stepper__input").on('change', function() {
var total = 0;
  $(".stepper__input").each((a,b) => total += +b.value * $(b).data('value'));
  $("#total").html(total);
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.stepper {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.stepper__input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.stepper__input:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
}

.stepper__input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.stepper__input::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.stepper__controls [spinner-button="up"],
.stepper__controls [spinner-button="down"] {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: all ease 0.25s;
}

.stepper__controls [spinner-button="up"]:hover,
.stepper__controls [spinner-button="down"]:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  border-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.stepper--style-2 {
  max-width: 140px;
}

.stepper--style-2 .stepper__input {
  padding-left: 3.25rem;
  padding-right: 3.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="up"],
.stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="down"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 2.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="up"] {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.stepper--style-2 [spinner-button="down"] {
  left: 0;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<section>

<div>total<span id="total"></span></div>
  <p>Stepper 1</p>
  <div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="10">
    <div class="stepper__controls">
      <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
      <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Stepper 2</p>
  <div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="20">
    <div class="stepper__controls">
      <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
      <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Stepper 3</p>
  <div class="stepper stepper--style-2 js-spinner">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" class="stepper__input" data-value="30">
    <div class="stepper__controls">
      <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
      <button type="button" spinner-button="down">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/stepper.js@1.0.3/dest/stepper.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I did not quite understand how this code works. Can you please explain?

Comment: Using jQuery, we assign `onchange` event to all inputs, whenever there is a change we loop through all inputs, take sum and assign the number to the `total` span using `.html()`

Comment: Thank you! I like this solution too!